# ArrayList.Add with Object Creates Chaos

Tags: excel, vba, arraylist

I'm sorry for the broad characterization of "chaos" in the title, but I really don't know how else to describe it. What I'm trying to do is build a macro in Excel to parse and organize a large number of financial entries from one file into another. To do that, I first read in the entries, and debug output to that stage seems to indicate that the parsing up to the point is fine. But then I was putting them in an ArrayList and when I tried to read them back out the behavior was totally unexpected. When I added a breakpoint and tried to watch the process in the Local window, I saw that sometimes the number of entries would increment while other times it wouldn't, and frequently it looked like the newest entry was overwriting all the previous entries.

Below is a simplified example that re-creates the problem. What I think that this should do is create a worksheet titled "ADAM WEST" with ten charge entries with the hours incrementing from 1-10. What it actually does is create the sheet just fine, but with only one entry of 10 hours.

```
Sub DebugTest()
    Dim task As New sTask
    Dim this_charge As New sCharge
    For i = 1 To 10
        this_charge.wbs_element = this_wbs
        this_charge.nwa = "NWA123456"
        this_charge.nwa_title = "TEST NWA"
        this_charge.name = "ADAM WEST"
        this_charge.post_date = "03/15/2024"
        this_charge.hours = i
        this_charge.log_date = "03/14/2024"
        this_charge.labor_cost = "100"
        Call task.AddLaborCharge(this_charge)
    Next i
    task.ProcessLaborCharges
End Sub
```

```
' Class Module: sTask

Dim laborcharge_array As New ArrayList

Public Sub AddLaborCharge(charge As sCharge)
    laborcharge_array.Add charge
End Sub

Public Sub ProcessLaborCharges()
    Dim charge As sCharge
    Dim employee As sEmployee
    For Each charge In laborcharge_array
        Set employee = GetEmployee(charge.name)
        Dim employee_charges As Worksheet
        Set employee_charges = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(charge.name)
        Dim next_row As Integer
        next_row = employee_charges.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        employee_charges.Cells(next_row, 1).Value = charge.wbs_element
        employee_charges.Cells(next_row, 2).Value = charge.nwa
        employee_charges.Cells(next_row, 3).Value = charge.nwa_title
        employee_charges.Cells(next_row, 4).Value = charge.hours
        employee_charges.Cells(next_row, 5).Value = charge.labor_cost
        employee_charges.Cells(next_row, 6).Value = charge.log_date
        employee_charges.Cells(next_row, 7).Value = charge.post_date
    Next charge
End Sub
```

I'm much more comfortable with C++ and Python, so it's very likely I'm missing something obvious in the VBA world.

Comment: `sCharge` is a class, I assume?

Comment: Oops - yes, I meant to include the definition of that as well. But right now it's just the properties that you see defined.

Comment: @AndrewBouchard slight quibble, but you're not actually using properties per se. Otherwise you'd have `Property Get`, and `Property Let`/`Property Set` procedures in your class.

Comment: Apologies - you are correct. I'm terrible with terminology...

Comment: What value are you using for `this_wbs`?

Comment: Thanks - I had actually just caught that myself. That was a copy-paste error and it wasn't defined in the scope of the test macro. Changing that to a simple string ("WBS123456.789" in my case) got the solution below to work.

Comment: Yes, if `this_wbs` is an empty string you'll overwrite data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `DebugTest()`, the `task.AddLaborCharge()` method does **NOT** make a new object or copy the data from the `this_charge` variable. Rather, it adds a reference to the same single object created at the beginning.

The code then loops several times, mutating this *same object* and adding a reference (not a copy!) to the collection each time, so at the end you have a list with a bunch of references to the same object that has been changed a bunch of times... but all the references point to the same item that now matches the values from the final loop iteration.

Instead, you should create a *new instance* of the `sCharge` object for each iteration *inside the loop*:

```vb
Sub DebugTest()
    Dim task As New sTask   
    Dim this_charge As sCharge 
    For i = 1 To 10
        Set this_charge = new sCharge
        this_charge.wbs_element = this_wbs
        this_charge.nwa = "NWA123456"
        this_charge.nwa_title = "TEST NWA"
        this_charge.name = "ADAM WEST"
        this_charge.post_date = "03/15/2024"
        this_charge.hours = i
        this_charge.log_date = "03/14/2024"
        this_charge.labor_cost = "100"
        Call task.AddLaborCharge(this_charge)
    Next i
    task.ProcessLaborCharges
End Sub
```

---

It's worth nothing we also have this code inside the `AddLaborCharge()` method:

```
laborcharge_array.Add charge
```

VB has a long-standing convention of using parentheses (or not) for method arguments to control whether they are passed by reference or by value. However, if the `sCharge` type is a reference type... ie a `Class` rather than a `Structure`... then even when passed by value, *the value of the variable is still just a reference*.

Comment: Be careful: While your explanation is correct, you implementation fails: `Dim this_charge As New sCharge` will **not** create a new object for every iteration. You will need to use `Dim this_charge As sCharge : Set this_charge  = new sCharge`

Comment: @FunThomas Makes sense. I do a LOT more vb.net code, so I sometimes forget the differences to vba/vbscript. I'll make an adjustment.